# SQLAlchemy Core metadata.create_all() trying to create tables outside Python process

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy 0.7.8 and Python 2.7 (also observed with Python 2.6).

I have a script that will read a table X from a database and create table X1.

My database has tables A, B, C, D.  I start four completely separate processes to create tables A1, B1, C1, D1.

What I'm observing is a sort of race condition where the metadata.create_all() in the B process is also trying to create the table A1 and is failing because A1 has already been created by process A.  Using checkfirst=True explicitly (which is the default anyway) doesn't help.

I don't understand why metadata.create_all() for process B tries to create non-B tables at all.  How does it even know that other processes are working on other tables?  I can explore ways of doing what I need without using create_all(), but this seems weird.  It's on a Postgres 9.2 server if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are there any dependencies, like foreign keys, between tables A and B?

Comment: posting some code might help. also why not using `create` instead of `create_all`? In general, you probably share `engine` or `MetaData` instance between the processes, which is causing the problem.

Comment: @van Yes, I can probably do create() rather than create_all() but my point in asking this question is to understand the behavior.  

It certainly looks like the engine or metadata is shared between the process, but I don't see how this happens.  They aren't forked from the same python process or anything; I execute from the shell "python script.py  . . ." for each.  Does creating an engine or metadata do something in the DB itself that the second process is somehow hooking on to?

Comment: @9000 No dependencies between the tables.

Comment: if you do run them as separate shell commands, I do not see how they can share metadata. I think you should search for the cause elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one model sharing the same metadata? Quite likely (this is the default way).

Quoting [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html?highlight=create_all#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all):

> Create all tables stored in this metadata.

So the mere presence of all tables' *descriptions* in a script makes `create_all` create these tables. If you know which table(s) to create, you either invoke `create()` on that table, or pass the list of models to `create_all()` and let it sort out any the correct creation order.

Comment: I'm not sure what "model" means in this context, but given van's last comment to the original question, it does sound like two separate shell processes can't share the metadata.  And, of course, now I'm unable to reproduce the result.  I'll return with some more info if I see it again.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: 'Model' usually means the ORM model classes that represent your tables. I hope you've overcome the problem by now!